# Unable to open Eclipse after update

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, error-log

Eclipse installed some updates today and I guess something did not go well during the process because from there I can not launch at all. I got a very long message in the log file, however I do not know how to fix the issue.
Please see the begining (it contains near 3000 lines) of the Log file below:

```
!SESSION 2022-03-28 23:43:49.143 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.23.0.I20220308-0310
java.version=15.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=es_ES
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.buildship.core 4 0 2022-03-28 23:43:50.691
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.buildship.core [52]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.filesystem
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.expressions
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.expressions; bundle-version="3.8.100.v20210910-0640"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.core.expressions [62]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.3.0,4.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1840)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1781)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1745)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.buildship.stsmigration 4 0 2022-03-28 23:43:50.736
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.buildship.stsmigration [53]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1840)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1781)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1745)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.buildship.ui 4 0 2022-03-28 23:43:50.752
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.buildship.ui [54]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.buildship.core
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.buildship.core; bundle-version="3.1.5.v20210113-0929"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.buildship.core [52]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.filesystem
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.expressions
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.expressions; bundle-version="3.8.100.v20210910-0640"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.core.expressions [62]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.3.0,4.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1840)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1781)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1745)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.compare.core 4 0 2022-03-28 23:43:50.752
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.compare.core [56]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1840)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1781)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1745)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

Comment: All that can be said from the log is that the installation is broken, but not why it is broken (e.g. even the general plugin/bundle `org.eclipse.core.runtime` cannot be resolved/loaded). Try a fresh installation. Plugins from the old installation can maybe imported via _File > Import...: Install > From Existing Installation_. Did you delete or modify any files of the installation at any time before or after the update?

Comment: thank you. That is what I did, install latest version and now apparently all works ok.